# how to use a project as module in another project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, module, project

I've two android projects `project:Main` and `project:Sub`. When I am using `Project:Main` there is a Button, if i click That Button `Project:Sub` have to be Run in Same App. for that how i've to import `project:Sub` into `project:Main` like module, library,...etc any help how to import one project into another project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Import Project as a Module

From menu File -> New -> Import Project /Import Module. Depending on what you are importing.

Then you need to check the dependency in the Project Structure Settings.